# AddThis-Facebook share Image Size

Tags: facebook, addthis

I am using AddThis-Facebook Share feature in my website but somehow the image that I defined in the meta width and height is not being pulled over to Facebook. The image size is smaller when appearing in the Facebook Share window. I have used the Facebook Debugger and the height and width are indeed stated. May I know how do I get the same size as what I have defined in the meta tag to appear in the Share?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youth.sg%2FOur-Voice%2FYour-Take%2F2017%2F4%2FA-cycle-of-issues-for-new-bicycle-sharing-service

Appreciate anyone who can advise.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: I have read already but I am not sure whether does Facebook do a resize for me even if the recommended image size is being used.

Comment: Your image is 320*213px - that is far from the recommended size.